# After I put my computer on sleep, when I turn it back on, my screen freeze like this. Why?

Tags: 11.10, freeze, login-screen, screen, sleep

I use ubuntu 11.10. My display freeze when I put my computer on sleep. So on wake-up, I'm forced to restart it. I tried with 2 differents screen and same result. Why?

PS: I would upload a screen-shot but my reputation points is not high enough.

Comment: It would be helpful to add some detail, Marc.  What kind of video card (nvidia, ati/amd, intel), you've tagged 11.10, but did this work on 11.04 (if you tried it), is a 32-bit or 64-bit installation?

Comment: **If** you have you an older **Intel GPU** (embedded graphics) and are using **Unity-2D**, then duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72692/system-freeze-on-exit-from-screensaver-unity-2d-older-intel-gpu

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you still have computer and mouse, but without a screen I'm not sure how you know this?

One thing to try - press CTRL-ALT-F1 to switch to another terminal.  If you see the terminal output, which is just a few lines of text at the top of a black screen, then this is just an issue with waking your screen up properly after resume, usually fixed by blacklisting certain modules from sleeping when you suspend.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the display freezes when it wakes up, or when it goes to sleep?

When you say you tried with two different screens, what do you mean exactly? Did you plug in different monitors?

Some computers unfortunately don't support sleep with linux (or don't do it very well) so you might be stuck :(

Comment: The display freeze when it wake up. The mouse or keyboard don't freeze, only display. I tried one my one, two different screen and same result. So the problem don't come from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with my Netbook (MSI U100). My research pointed to issues with my onboard mini-PCI wireless card (Realtek). I had a spare Intel card around the house and decided to crack the machine open and swap. Sure enough the freezing issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens on my EeeBox with 11.10, the monitor goes to sleep after 20 min while I'm using it, and I can't wake it up. It didn't do that with 11.04.

Comment: Which graphics chip?  Are you using **Unity** or **Unity-2D** ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on a Dell Inspiron 9400 with a Nvidia graphic card, and when it wakes up from a suspend, Unity is unable to restart. I can go back to LightDM, but unable to do a clean restart. At this point the only solution is to force shutdown by pressing the power button then restart.

I'll try running another environment to see if it changes something... A question : could it be my swap partition which is 1,5 GB as my RAM goes up to 3.2 GB ?

That didn't occur on 11.04 with the same swap.

Regards,
Clysthène.

Comment: So ! After further tests, Unity is guilty ! When I log on with Gnome, and put the computer on sleep, it wakes up nicely... Let's wait for an update. :(

Comment: Here's a dirty solution : when jammed, connect into a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1 for instance) then type "unity --replace", once the process stops, return to the environment (Ctrl+Alt+F7) then logout (there won't be any confirmation dialog so type Enter to confirm) then re-log, you're settled without reboot !

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try the suggestion on [this site](http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug) to fix the wake from suspend issue, I tried it myself but it did not work for my system.